# split a string by comma in postgres

Tags: postgresql

There is a table in my postgres database that contains 4 digit years in a string format concat with each other -

```
rollno | year
-----------------------------------
00001  | 201220132014
-----------------------------------
00002  | 2013201420152016
-----------------------------------
00003  | 2015
-----------------------------------
```

I have above data in my postgres table, I want my data to be separated by comma as below example :

```
rollno | year
-----------------------------------
00001  | 2012,2013,2014
-----------------------------------
00002  | 2013,2014,2015,2016
-----------------------------------
00003  | 2015
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Fix your design. Normalize your tables instead of looking for complicated queries

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex `(\d)(?=(\d{4})+$)` with `\1,` as replacement.

```
update yourTable
set year = regexp_replace(year, '(\d)(?=(\d{4})+$)', '\1,', 'g')
```

However, this query is actually taking you in the wrong direction, because it results in having CSV data in your `year` column.  Instead, each year should ideally be in a separate record to keep your database normalized.

Comment: No it does not make it comma separated still. It just return the same string

Comment: I tested this locally on my Postgres and it works.  What _type_ is your `year` column?  Is it numeric or text?

Comment: Its character varying

Comment: It runs for me without any problems, I cannot help you further.

Comment: @Curious: Tim's solution works, see here: http://rextester.com/SYOP26824 If it doesn't work for you then you probably forgot to tell some details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
update tbl1
set vl = t.yr
from (
    select id
        ,string_agg(y, ',') yr
    from (
        select id
            ,unnest(regexp_split_to_array(vl, E '(?=(....)+$)')) y
        from tbl1
        ) s
    group by id
    ) t
where t.id = tbl1.id
```